# On my Facebook ad page, should the "Download App" button link to my app's Google Play store page or start the download feature directly?

Tags: facebook

I just need tips for best practice and also what is possible. Can we link our FB pages's "Install App" button to the Play Store page's download feature directly? Many thanks

Comment: I think that will only go to the app store URL, the user is supposed to be able to check the detailed app description there, before they decide whether they want to install it or not.